# POST the value of select option to another page PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, ajax, post

I need to POST the value of the selected option to use in a query on another page.

This is my form:

```
<form method="post" data-remote="true">
        <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="switch-area">
            <?php while($test3 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($test2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) : ?>
                <option data-tokens="<?php echo $test3['Name'] ?>" value="<?php echo $test3['Name'] ?>"><?php echo $test3['Name'] ?></option> 
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </select>
    <button class="btn btn-info">View Area</button>                    
</form>
```

I am using ajax and this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="switch-area"]').change(function(){
        var status = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'sim-area.php',
                data: {changeStatus: status}
         });
    });
});
```

Then on sim-area.php this is my code to grab the data:

```
$selectedArea = $_POST['switch-area'];
```

But I keep getting an undefined index error, am I posting this in the correct way?

Comment: change `$_POST['switch-area'];` to `$_POST['changeStatus'];`

Comment: Or if you want switch-area variable :  data: {switch-area: status}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending `changeStatus` but not `switch-area` in your `data`, you want

```
$selectedArea = $_POST['changeStatus'];
```